# how to increase button id when button clicks

Tags: javascript, html, yii2

I have a button, when click the button i need to increase the button id
This is my button

```
 <input type="button" id="repeataddon-1" name="repeataddon"
 class="repeataddon" value="add" >
```

and the script as

```
 $(document).on( "click",'.repeataddon',function( ) {
                     hoteladdons();
                     alert(this.id);
                 });
```

can i use this code for my other table attributes which i want to increase their id as the same

```
<table width="100%" class="book-table" >
    <tr>
        <th>Addon Name</th>
        <th>No of Addons</th>
        <th>Rate</th>
        <th>Addon Amount</th>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <article>
                <span>

          <?php echo $hoteladdon; ?>

              </span>
            </article>
        </td>
        <td>
            <article>
                             <span>
                    <select class="noofaddons" name="noofaddons" id="noofaddons-1">
                        <?php
                        for($i=0;$i<5;$i++){


                            echo "<option value='$i'>".$i."</option>";

                        }
                        ?>
                    </select>
                        </span>
            </article>
        </td>
        <td><label id="addonprice-msg-1"></label> </td>
        <td><label id="addontotal-msg-1"></label></td>

    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: would it not be better to keep track of somethign like this in a data-value instead?

Comment: Use data-attributes instead to store some extra information. Or even better - use JavaScript variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I did:

```
$(document).on("click", '.repeataddon, .noofaddons, .addonprice-msg, .addontotal-msg', function () {
     var sp = $(this).attr('id').split("-");

     if (isNaN(sp[sp.length - 1]) == false) {
         $(this).attr('id', $(this).attr('id').split("-").slice(0, $(this).attr('id').split("-").length - 1).join("-") + '-' + (parseInt($(this).attr('id').split("-")[$(this).attr('id').split("-").length - 1]) + 1));
     } else {
         $(this).attr('id', $(this).attr('id') + '-1');
     }
 });
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/693pcge6/1/)

Inspect element to see the change while you click on the button

Comment: it's correct.. i don't know why you should use the id selector als counter, it is just plain stupid.. but this is the answer he asked :)

Comment: ..can you please help me..i edited my question...thanks in advance

Comment: The code I provided will increase the _id_ of any element having the class `repeataddon`, assuming the _id_ is in the form `repeataddon-[numberHere]`. I can't find any element with similar _id_ in the html you provided, can you please check again?

Comment: no...not like that...here i want to increase the id of 'noofaddons','addonprice-msg','addontotal-msg'

Comment: @MaRKR They don't really have a number in their _id_. Do you mean the number should be added as `noofaddons-1`...?

Comment: exactly...as you said

Comment: @MaRKR I edited the code and the link to the updated JSFiddle :)

Answer (score 2):

Just like below

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.repeataddon').click(function() {
    // hoteladdons();
    var temp = $(this).attr('id').split('-');
    $(this).attr('id', temp[0] + '-' + (parseInt(temp[1]) + 1));
    console.log($(this).attr('id'));
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="repeataddon-1" name="repeataddon" class="repeataddon" value="add">
```

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, I'm not familiar with jQuery, and I updated my code.